# High CPU command for perfview explanation

Tags: logging, cpu-usage, perfmon, perfview

I am running this command to collect high cpu issues with Perfview with a threshold of 75.  As you can see its doing something already, collecting stuff.  Also there seems to be a 3 second trigger.  I want this to collect and not take up space until 75 is hit, but doesnt look to be doing that.  Also can I set the trigger to a larger number, looks to be 3 when over 75?

```
PerfView /NoGui collect /StopOnPerfCounter=Process:% Processor Time:w3wp#6>75 -ThreadTime -CircularMB:1000 -CollectMultiple:5 -accepteula
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used the Stop trigger but wanted a Start trigger, so change it to

```
Perfview /NoGui collect "/StartOnPerfCounter=Process:% Processor Time:w3wp>75" -ThreadTime -CircularMB:1000 -CollectMultiple:5 –accepteula
```

and add the `/MinSecForTrigger:VALUE` parameter to override the default 3s value.

Comment: You know what this answer is? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69455605/perfview-command-trigger-being-executed-incorrectly-on-threshold