# Perfview command trigger being executed incorrectly on threshold

Tags: logging, iis, perfmon, w3wp, perfview

I am trying to get Perfview to execute when the W3WP service goes over 90% CPU.  However it says 118.5? I am not sure where the number comes from but my CPU hasnt been above 20%.

[image]

Comment: I tested it and it works for me . I don't see a value over 100. which windows do you use? Also make sure you use latest [PerfView release](https://github.com/microsoft/perfview/releases/latest)

Comment: Here’s a better screen shot. Notice the 101.5? What are those numbers?

Comment: yes, I see it on your picture, but not on my system. Is this a VM? Virtualbox has performance monitor issues that can result in wrong values.

Comment: It’s on Azure VM. Keeps executing although the CPU never hit over the threshold for 10 seconds

Comment: try it on a local Windows

Comment: Why would I try it on local?

Comment: perfcounters can be tricky inside VMs so if it works on local windows you know that the VM is the cause

Comment: does it work locally?